# Determine Rehire Precedence with Firm

Tags: termination

I am wanting to find out how to determine if there is precedences at a company for re-hiring persons who were terminated from the firm.  I need ideas on how to find out this information.

REVISION - Thanks for all of the answers all good for a termination reentry. Here is a revision to the question -->  **I am wanting to know WHERE / HOW I can determine without contacting the firm directly if anyone else who has been terminated from the firm and has been rehired at the firm to determine precedence for the re-hire.** Please respond to the revised question as it more accurately reflects the question.

Comment: Call the firm's HR department and ask. Some companies and departments do have specific policy about this, the only way to know is to ask. There isn't a universal standard and we can't determine a given company's policy for you.

Comment: What country are you in?  If it's the US the answer is 'whatever they feel like'

Comment: Remember, in the USA, you can't be terminated without just cause.....  Although, sometimes that means "just 'cause we felt like it"

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers all good for a termination reentry.  I am wanting to know WHERE / HOW I can determine without contacting the firm directly if anyone else who has been terminated from the firm and has been rehired at the firm to determine precedence.

Comment: @RichardU Really?  Most states in the US are at-will, which means an employer can get rid of an employee for no reason at all.  I agree with the last part of your comment anyway.

Comment: If you're in the USA (and most answerers will assume this unless told otherwise) there's no law governing it and no requirement to publicly disclose the policy, so asking the company directly is the only option.  If you're elsewhere, please tell us what country, so that someone familiar with your local laws can give an appropriate answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, I made a joke.. you know... "just cause"  and "just 'cause we felt like it".... you know, these jokes are a lot funnier when I don't have to explain them.

Comment: "Determine Rehire Precedence" starts by assuming there even is such a thing as "Rehire Precedence". Never mind asking the company; ask yourself why you think such a thing would even exist. Real companies have a one-bit precedence, rehire/don't rehire.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reach out to the company and ask, but that information may be confidential.

From my experience employees that are terminated for performance/policy/disciplinary reasons are not re-hired.  The ones that were terminated for budgetary reasons are sometimes re-hired.

Answer (score 4):

I would contact HR directly and ask if there is a rehire policy, and what the terms are, follow up by asking if, under their policy, you would be eligible for a rehire.  They may or may not tell you, depending on whether or not their policy is confidential.

Also, connect with current and former employees, any friends you may have that still work there, et cetera.  Try to form back channels and see if you can network your way back in.

Social media such as linkedin and FB may provide leads.

Then, should you find an opening, go for it very aggressively.  An employee who has been terminated for cause is going to have to put forth an extraordinary effort that has to convince the company that that person has learned the error of their ways and will not only be a good employee, but an outstanding one.

Answer (score 4):

> how to determine

If someone is terminated for money or policy reasons but eligible for rehire, they are usually told at the time. In some instances I have seen with govt jobs people have been laid off with a huge pay out and then after a brief rest at home rehired into the same position.

If someone is terminated for stealing, incompetence or anything like that then the chances of rehiring are very low, although I have seen it done in places where there are no options due to a small human resource pool in the locale.